# Collision detection not working HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason this collision detection algorithm is not working. I'm expecting the alert hello to be printed to the screen when the collision occurs, however this does not happen. I believe it has something to do with the return statement, am I missing something obvious here ?

```
 // checkHit is called in the game loop

        Player.prototype.checkHit = function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
            var colliding = testCollisionEntity(this, enemies[i]);
            if (colliding) {
              alert('hello');
            }
          }
        };


        testCollisionEntity = function (entity1,entity2){ 
          var rect1 = {
            x: entity1.x - entity1.width / 2,
            y: entity1.y - entity1.height / 2,
            width: entity1.width,
            height: entity1.height,
          }

          var rect2 = {
            x: entity2.x - entity2.width / 2,
            y: entity2.y - entity2.height / 2,
            width: entity2.width,
            height: entity2.height,
          }

          return testCollisionRectRect(rect1,rect2);
        }


        testCollisionRectRect = function(rect1,rect2) {
          return rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width
            && rect2.x <= rect1.x + rect1.width
            && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height
            && rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.height;
        }
```

Comment: Are the width/x and height/y units the same? Are they pixels? Are they a certain (e.g. 32) number of pixels? How are you getting/updating them? Why are you passing 8 pieces of information to your collision detection function when it only needs 4? Are you sure those should all be `&&`'s? Bounding should be `a && b || c && d` usually. I'm thinking your logic doesn't describe an obtainable state.

Comment: Thanks Jared, you made me figure this out. Many thanks

Comment: I'll post as an answer, please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
(rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.height) ||
(rect2.x <= rect1.x + rect1.width && rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.height)
```